# Is eta-expansion foolproof in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Is it best to always eta-expand as a fool-proof rule of thumb in OCaml ?

```ml
  type 'x recordx = { x : int }
  type 'y recordy = { y : int }

  let rec ok : type n a. n recordx -> a recordy -> int =
   fun algebrah x -> ok algebrah x

  let rec ok : type a. a recordy -> int =
   fun x ->
    let go : type b. b recordy -> int = ok in
    go x

  let rec ok : type n a. n recordx -> a recordy -> int =
   fun x y ->
    let go : type b. b recordy -> int = fun y -> ok x y in
    go y

  let rec ok : type n a. n recordx -> a recordy -> int =
   fun x y ->
    let go = ok x in
    go y

  (* This definition has type 
          'b recordy -> int which is less general than
    'b0. 'b0 recordy -> int 
  *)
  let rec ko : type n a. n recordx -> a recordy -> int =
   fun x y ->
    let go : type b. b recordy -> int = ko x in
    go y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relaxed value restriction classifies the eta-expanded form `fun y -> f x y` as a value that can thus be generalized by let bindings, contrarily to the non-value `f y`. See https://ocaml.org/manual/polymorphism.html#s%3Aweak-polymorphism .

Moreover, in a eager language like OCaml, eta-expansion does change the semantics of functions. Consider

```ml
let print x =
  Format.printf "x=%s@." x;
  fun y -> Format.printf "y=%s@."
```

and

```ml
let print1 = print "x"
let print2 y = print "x" y
```

Thus, eta-expansion is a semantic-changing transformation rather than a "foolproof" transformation.

Comment: indeed but that has nothing to do with the type system (which doesn't track side effect). what's surprising to me was the type error.

Comment: It has everything to do with the type system. The value restriction fixes a possible unsoundness in the type system in the presence of mutable variables and polymorphism.

Comment: You are right, the side effect tracking is implicit with the "weak polymorphism" (aka static type application). and it thus destroys polymorphism preventively upon calling functions.